# New line after variable in C

Tags: c, variables, printf, newline

In C, I try to do \n after a variable.

Here is my source code:

```
int main() {
    int xD = 21;
    printf(xD\n);
}
```

And I receive this while compiling it:

```
new 1.c: In function ‘main’:
new 1.c:5:11: error: stray ‘\’ in program
printf(xd\n);
       ^
new 1.c:5:12: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘n’
printf(xd\n);
        ^
new 1.c:5:9: warning: format not a string literal and no format
arguments [-Wformat-security]
printf(xd\n);
       ^~
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Hmm. The last time this question was [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778553/printing-a-int-variable-in-c/13778579) it was closed for being "too localized".

Comment: For an example of why `printf` was designed this way, see [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Format_placeholder_specification) that shows how the format string can add useful info to your output.

Comment: even the error message is different from your code: `xD` vs `xd`

Comment: Your error and your code don't match; just for consistency, which is it, `xd` or `xD`? (you don't need to answer in a comment, just edit the question to correct it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The printf function requires a format parameter to identify the type of variable xD is.  Since xD is an integer, "%d" is required as the format parameter.

```
printf("%d\n", xD);
```

Answer (score 5):

There are two problems here:
1. `printf()` expects the first argument to be a `const char*` string specifying the format.
2. The compiler doesn't know how to interpret `\n` outside of a string (quotes).  This is what prevents it from compiling.

Even if you removed the `\n`, attempting to `printf(xd)` is asking `printf()` to treat xd (an integer) as the format string --  and that's not going to work for you.  In fact, C will likely attempt to do an implicit cast of `xd` to `const char*`.  You're asking `printf()` to interpret the "array of characters located at address 21" as the format string (and there's almost certainly no format string there).

What you really meant to say was:

```
printf("%d\n", xd);
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the string to format:

```
printf("%d\n",xD);
```